# Integer comparison within score board app, score difference equal two

Tags: javascript

I'm writting an score board app.
Got two integers, i need to compare them, for example

- to know when game should be ended, eg. score = 20:22, 24:26 (score difference to end the game should be equal to two)

How i can make such comparison with js?

Comment: your question should be more specific, please try to provide some more details

Comment: what wrong with Math.abs(score1 - score2)  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs ?

Comment: why create the `string` out of `numbers` then back to `number` for comparing?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split()` method to separate scores into two different elements, and then afterwards just compare them.

```
function isGameOver(score, differenceToWin) {
  var scoreArray = score.split(":");
  return Math.abs(scoreArray[0] - scoreArray[1]) > differenceToWin;
}

isGameOver('24:26', 2)
```

EDIT: In case you only need to compare two integers, go ahead and use only the return statement line:

```
var score1 = 24;
var score2 = 26;
var differenceToWin = 2;
var isGameOver = Math.abs(score1 - score2) > differenceToWin;
```

Comment: They mentioned "got two integers" so I don't think this is a string split issue.